# Get bool if a Nvidia or a AMD GPU card is installed

Tags: java, opencl, lwjgl, amd-gpu

I need to somehow to get a list of the GPUs installed and available to use and for each GPU detected i need to get the brand name of it using Java.

Only on Windows

Comment: You may use vulkan or opencl for that

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible with pure Java.

You will need platform specific solution.

Comment: Using any java library for windows